# Can a service principal or azure app admin consent an external multi tenant app registration?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We have multiple tenants we manage.  Currently when i create a multi tenant app registration I need to one by one load the admin consent url in a browser and log in as an admin at each client(tenant).  This is a tedious process.  I used to be able to use powershell and a password database to login-azurermaccount and get a refresh token to use at this endpoint

"https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/RegisteredApplications/$azureAppId/Consent?onBehalfOfAll=true"

to approve the app at each of the clients. However now with MFA and hardened security I can no longer log in as an admin programmatically to approve the app on each tenant. Which brings me to my question.

Can I use a service principal account created at each client that I can then use to sign in programmatically to approve app registrations for that client?  Or is only a regular admin account with a username/password allowed to approve apps?

Does anyone have example working code of this process?

Thank You,

-----TESTS PERFORMED-------

I created an app registration with the Directory.ReadWrite.All permission.

I tested code similar to this and different variations with no luck.  i get different errors depending on the what resource i enter

Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/.default was not found in the tenant name

or

Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

```
 $body = @{
        grant_type    = "client_credentials"
        client_id     = $clientId
        client_secret = $clientSecret
        resource      = $resourceAppIdURI
    }
    $oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Body $body

 $header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiToken.access_token
    'X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'
    'x-ms-client-request-id'= [guid]::NewGuid()
    'x-ms-correlation-id' = [guid]::NewGuid()}
    $url = "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/RegisteredApplications/$azureAppId/Consent?onBehalfOfAll=true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: To Grant Admin consent to the API permissions of the Azure AD Application, one must have Global Administrator, Privileged Role Administrator or Application Administrator role.

I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

For **sample**, I tried to **grant Admin Consent** using the below Microsoft Graph query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants

Request body
{
   "clientId": "ClientID",
   "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
   "resourceId": "ResourceID",
   "scope": "User.Read.All Group.Read.All"
}
```

I got **401 unauthorized** error:

[image]

> Can I use a service principal account created at each client that I can then use to sign in programmatically to approve app registrations for that client? Or is only a regular admin account with a username/password allowed to approve apps?

Try granting **Application Administrator role** or any of the required roles to the Application and try granting Admin consent.

Login with the **Azure Service Principal using az login** like below:

```bash
az login --service-principal -u "AppID" -p "ClientSecret" -t "TenantID"
```

[image]

Now **generate the access token**:

```json
az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com
```

[image]

To grant **Admin Consent for the delegated permissions** using the below Curl request:

```json
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants'  \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <bearertoken_ruk>' \  
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \  
--data-raw '{  
"clientId": "ObjectIDofSP",  
"consentType": "AllPrincipals",   
"resourceId": "MsGraphID",  
"scope": "Group.ReadWrite.All"  
}
```

[image]

To **grant Admin Consent for Application permissions**, using the below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/SpID/appRoleAssignedTo

{
   "principalId": "PrincipalID",
   "resourceId": "ResourceID",
   "appRoleId": "ID"
}
```

The **Admin consent granted successfully to the API permissions** like below:

[image]

**Note**: It might take few minutes delay to reflect Admin Consent in the Portal.

**References:**

[How to grant admin consent to an API programmatically | by Sahil Malik](https://winsmarts.com/how-to-grant-admin-consent-to-an-api-programmatically-e32f4a100e9d)

[Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=ms-graph)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Rukmini.   I am adding the following to make it explicitly clear what these are for anyone else who has trouble understanding what the Microsoft terms mean.

APP ROLE ID

The App Role ID is the guid of the permission you are adding.  Our example is for User.Read.All (this is global for all clients & graph api, it is microsoft hard coded into graph api)

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=displayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'&$select=id,displayName,appId,appRoles

RESOURCE ID

The Resource ID - is the guid for Microsoft Graph API itself.  This is tenant environment dependent.  It is found at the top of the json returned from here (same url as above).

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=displayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'&$select=id,displayName,appId,appRoles

PRINCIPAL ID

The Principal Id - is the guid for the App registration created that all tenants will need to approve.  this stays the same for every approval request
The object id is NOT the same object id you find in the GUI app registrations via portal.azure.com.  You need to use powershell to get the actual object id.

Connect-AzureAD

Get-AzureADServicePrincipal

Find the app registration and get the object id

Or if you prefer a graph api endpoint to get the service principal for the app registration:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals